# Explaining Ghidra pointer (ELI don't know about C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, ghidra

Given `param_1` is the input file bytes, can someone explains what does `uVar4 = *(uint *)(param_1 + 3)` do? Is it casting `param_1` to `uint` then `uVar4 = param_1[3]`?
Also any clarification about pointer is also good bc my experience with C/Cpp is close to nil (not even mentioning pointers)

```
uchar * DecryptLZ4(uchar *param_1,ulong param_2,ulong *param_3) //param_1: file bytes, param_2: file size

{
  uchar uVar1;
  uchar *puVar2;
  int iVar3;
  uint uVar4;
  bool bVar5;
  ulong local_28;
  int local_24;
  
  local_24 = __stack_chk_guard;
  local_28 = param_2;
  if (((param_1 != (uchar *)0x0) && (6 < param_2)) && (*param_1 == -8)) { //if param_1[0] == 0xf8..
    uVar1 = param_1[1];
    bVar5 = uVar1 == -0x75; // ..and param_1[1] == 0x8b:
    if (bVar5) { 
      uVar1 = param_1[2];
    } // if param_1[0] = 
    if (((bVar5 && uVar1 == '+') && (param_2 != 7)) && //if param_1[2] == 0x2b and param_2 != 7
       (uVar4 = *(uint *)(param_1 + 3), uVar4 < 0x2000001)) { // THIS LINE
      puVar2 = (uchar *)Allocate((int)GlobalAllocator,(char *)(uVar4 + 1),
                                 (int)
                                 "XANA"
                                 ,&DAT_00000085);
      if (puVar2 != (uchar *)0x0) {
        iVar3 = FUN_00298230(param_1 + 7,puVar2,param_2 - 7,uVar4);
        if (iVar3 < 1) {
          Free((BlockAllocator *)GlobalAllocator,puVar2,(int)(char *)(uVar4 + 1));
          goto LAB_00346faa;
        }
        puVar2[iVar3] = '\0';
        Free((BlockAllocator *)GlobalAllocator,param_1,local_28 + 1);
        param_2 = uVar4;
        param_1 = puVar2;
        local_28 = uVar4;
      }
      if ((0 < (int)uVar4) && (2 < param_2)) {
        while (*param_1 == -8) {
          uVar1 = param_1[1];
          bVar5 = uVar1 != -0x75;
          if (!bVar5) {
            uVar1 = param_1[2];
          }
          if ((bVar5 || uVar1 != '+') ||
             (param_1 = (uchar *)DecryptLZ4(param_1,param_2,&local_28), param_2 = local_28,
             local_28 < 3)) break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
LAB_00346faa:
  if (param_3 != (ulong *)0x0) {
    *param_3 = param_2;
  }
  if (__stack_chk_guard == local_24) {
    return param_1;
  }
                    /* WARNING: Subroutine does not return */
  __stack_chk_fail();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the parentheses.

In `uVar4 = *(uint *)(param_1 + 3)`, the addition happens before the conversion to a pointer to `uint`. `param_1` has type `uchar *`.

So, it is not like `uVar4 = param_1[3]` because the expression `param_1[3]` has type `uchar`. This version would only load one byte, extended to (presumably) 4 bytes to be stored in `uVar4`. The original would copy (presumably) 4 bytes from the address `param_1 + 3` to `uVar4`.

---

My answer to

> Is it casting param_1 to uint then uVar4 = param_1[3]

would be no for two reasons:

- `param_1` has a fixed type (`uchar *`), casting it doesn't change its type.
- If you did something like `uint *param_2_ui = (uint *) param_1`, then `uVar4 = param_2_ui [3]`, the result would be different.

In C (and C++, though that it is a completely different language) adding to pointers will add to the address by the size of the pointed-to type.

In practice, assuming that `sizeof(int) == 4`, and given this:

```
int tmp[2];
int *ptr1 = tmp;
```

The expression `ptr1 + 1` will represent an address 4 greater than `ptr1`.

Comment: So for example the file I'm working on with the first 16 bytes:

`F8 8B 2B AB 7B 00 00 F0 12 4D 4E 47 A4 7B 00 00`

It will take `AB 7B 00 00` and store in uVar4 as uint type?

Comment: Yes, though you have to consider endianness to your processor. You could have the value 0xAB7B0000 or 0x00007BAB. You could even theoretically have some other value, on a weird architecture. This also assumes that `uint` is 4 bytes in size here. This is one of the main reasons why this sort of thing is somewhere between tricky and dangerous. The other is unaligned accesses, which could have no effect, a performance penalty, or raise an exception/cause a crash.

Comment: It's little-endian and ARMv8 so result should be 0x00007BAB (`unsigned int` for ARM is 4 bytes). Thank you so much for your thorough answer.